# syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php

Me surge este error en php cuando quiero hacer una consulta por fecha alguien sabe donde esta el error no logro encontrarlo.

```
$consulta1+="year(cast(cast(fch as datetime)-1 as date))= " .$anio1 "and month(cast(cast(fch as datetime)-1 as date))= " .$chkBox.$condicion. ") as s";
```

Pretendo pasar el valor de un año por medio de un combobox y del mes por medio del valor asignado a uno o varios checkbox.

Comment: Reemplazar por `$consulta1.='year(cast(cast(fch as datetime)-1 as date))= "'.$anio1.'" and month(cast(cast(fch as datetime)-1 as date))= " '.$chkBox.$condicion.' ") as s ';` Cuidado con las comillas simples y dobles en php

Comment: El detalle de las comillas simples es que no me reconoce las variables de php no se por que?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay dos errores en esa línea de código:

1. La concatenación en PHP se debe hacer con el punto  `.` pero estás asignando con `+=`. Deberías hacer `.=` o el resultado obtenido será 0 en lugar de la cadena deseada.
2. Te falta añadir una concatenación después de `$anio1` y eso es lo que realmente te causa el error que muestras.

Cambiando eso, ya funciona:

```
$consulta1.="year(cast(cast(fch as datetime)-1 as date))= " .$anio1. " and month(cast(cast(fch as datetime)-1 as date))= " .$chkBox.$condicion. ") as s";
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46380/discussion-on-answer-by-alvaro-montoro-syntax-error-unexpected-t-constant-encap).